# Swift attributed string part colored issue

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

I'm trying to change the second half of some text to a different color using range.

```
        let stringToColor = NSLocalizedString("Plan", comment: "")
        let mainString = title + ": "  + stringToColor
        let range = (mainString as NSString).range(of: stringToColor)
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: mainString)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.orange, range: range)
```

The text gets outputted but all one color, not the one set using `foregroundColor` key. Just can't see what the issue is.

ty

Comment: Your code works for me. Run your code through the debugger. Look at each value and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have an issue (Well I'd do it other way because `range(of:)` could cause issues). Question, on a `UILabel` or `UITextView`, do you correctly do `myLabel.attributedText = attrString` and not `myLabel.text = attrString.string`? Do you override `myLabel` properties at some point?

Comment: Q1: The first approach. Q2:  Tried both approaches

Comment: Correctly setting `.attributedText` fixed the issue. Thanks!